# python not recognizing function within imported module

Tags: python, function, module, attributes

I am working in Jupyter notebook. I created a simple module called conv.py for converting miles to km. When I try to import this module in a separate code (in the same directory) the import seems to go successfully but it doesn't recognize either of the functions I defined in the 'conv' module.

I have imported os and os.getcwd() provides the correct folder for conv.py...

**code for conv.py**

```
 in_n_ft = 12
 ft_n_mile = 5280
 m_n_km = 1000
 cm_n_in = 2.54
 cm_n_m = 100
 mm_n_m = 1000
 def ft_to_km(feet):
     return feet*in_n_ft*cm_n_in/cm_n_m/m_n_km
 print(ft_to_km(5280))
 def mil_to_km(mile):
     return mile*ft_n_mile*in_n_ft*cm_n_in/cm_n_m/m_n_km
    
 print(mil_to_km(3.2))
```

**Code for new module**

```
 import conv
 km = conv.mil_to_km(5)
```

**Error provided**

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-111-bfd778724ae2> in <module>
      3 import conv
      4 
----> 5 km = conv.mil_to_km(5)
AttributeError: module 'conv' has no attribute 'mil_to_km'
```

When I type

```
dir(conv)
```

I get

```
['__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__spec__']
```

What am I doing wrong?

***EDIT***

I have also tried

```
from conv import mil_to_km
```

when I do that I get a different error

```
cannot import name 'mil_to_km' from 'conv' (C:\Users\223023441\Documents\python\conv.py)
```

I have also queried the module using:

```
from inspect import getmembers, isfunction
import conv

print(getmembers(conv, isfunction))
```

from here I get:

```
['__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__spec__']
```

I am also unable to access any of the variables within the conv.py file after import... Am I doing something wrong when I save the py file? Jupyter makes ipynb as the common file, when I 'save as' to conv.py, is this screwing it up?

Comment: Does `conv.__file__` match the name the file you think you are importing?

Comment: Or did you edit the file without reloading it into the same iPython session? Simply "re"importing it won't work, because it will see that the module `conv` already exists and not re-import the file.

Comment: Even if you import your new module, if an old version of `conv` is already defined, the new module won't import the new version.

Comment: @chepner yes the name does match.  I just exited my python session and reloaded jupyter notebook from the CMD window (is this what you mean). Still having the same error

Comment: If you aren't seeing the output of the two `print` statements in `conv.py`, then you aren't importing that module.

Comment: @chepner I did log out of jupyter and closed it in my browser. Opened again from CMD and tried running my main file. No success

Comment: Please provide the exact paths of *all* the files you are importing or executing, along with the output of `conv.__file__` after the import.

Comment: @chepner So it looks like I am not importing the module then...

Comment: @chepner    C:\Users\XXXXXXXXX\Documents\python\     is the folder that both files are stored in                                
C:\Users\XXXXXXXXX\Documents\python\conv.py   is output of conv.__file__

Comment: How about `conv.__spec__`? (I'm grasping at straws, here; this isn't making any sense. *Something* is getting imported, or `import conv` would raise an error. But it's clearly not importing the `conv.py` shown, and I'm not sure what the other possibilities are.)

Comment: ModuleSpec(name='conv', loader=<_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x00000289CA47F6A0>, origin='C:\\Users\\223023441\\Documents\\python\\conv.py')    Am I saving the conv file correctly? notebook creates a .ipynb file for editing and I "saveas" and type conv.py on my own... Is this a problem?

Comment: It's not providing an error on the import but it doesn't seem to be importing anything. The variables should be defined as soon as I import it too correct? After importing, I can't access the variables either. So is something happening when I am saving the conv.py file?

Comment: And the origin is the same value as `conv.__file__`? I'm out of ideas here.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for trying. Something is telling me it is an issue with the way I am saving it...

Comment: @chepner it was def the way that I was saving the .py file in jupyter. See my answer on this page

Answer (score 1):

So the ultimate issue was the way I was saving the .py file... I was using the 'save as' command in jupyter notebook and typing 'conv.py' for my file save... This was showing up in the directory as a .py file, but my main file wasn't recognizing it properly. Once I downloaded the file as a .py file, cut from my downloads folder and pasted into my working directory everything worked...

Answer (score 0):

You should import `from` the module.
Try this:

```
from conv import mil_to_km

km = mil_to_km(5)
```

The reason is that when you import the module in that way, you are executing it.
In the way I shown, you are just importing the needed functions.

Comment: When I do that I get:    ImportError: cannot import name 'mil_to_km' from 'conv' (C:\Users\223023441\Documents\python\conv.py)

Comment: Sorry, i edit the answer; i mistakenly pasted conv.mil_to_km(5)  without removing conv. Try now

Comment: It fails before getting to that point. The error comes when trying to import mil_to_km from conv

Comment: are conv and main in the same directory?

Comment: The only difference between this and `import conv` is that the only name bound in the global scope is `mil_to_km`, and it's bound to the function in the module. The file itself is still (necessarily) executed to define the module, and the module in its entirety is still accessible from `sys.modules['conv']`.

Comment: Also, wouldn't I need to import the whole module as it contains the conversion factors that are used in mil_to_km?

Comment: They are in the same directory

Comment: As @chepner said, the file is still executed after you import it, so the conversion factors are declared the time when you import the conv module.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and took me several hours to resolve it. For me, when I restarted my Jupyter kernel everything worked normally and my functions were recognized.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).